# KiCad where is the priority setting of filled zones?

Tags: kicad

The [documentation](http://docs.kicad-pcb.org/5.0.2/en/pcbnew/pcbnew.html#creating_a_zone) shows a dialog for filled zones in which you can set up the priority of the zone.

I'm using KiCad 5.1.2 and I can't find this setting anywhere. Here's a screenshot of the filled zone dialog with 5.1.2:

[image]

It seems that the documentation is from 2017 which might be a bit old.

Where can I find this info?

Comment: thanks for the question! I never even knew there was a priority.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it were a snake, it would have bitten you :)

[image: Zone dialog with priority highlighted]